# Page keeps refreshing endlessly with Greasemonkey script

Tags: greasemonkey

I'm trying to click the first favourite link in the sidebar of stackoverflow.com.

I found this script, but the problem is that the page keeps refreshing endlessly.

Is there a way to stop this behavior?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _ChromeC
// @include  *//stackoverflow.com/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a major design
    change introduced in GM 1.0.
    It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("#interestingTags a", actionFunction);

function actionFunction (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: Uninstall the script after the first time?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What's unclear?

Comment: What do you mean with "uninstall the script"? Should I uninstall it and reinstall it every time I visit stackoverlow? XD

Comment: No, you should just uninstall it. What is confusing about this?

Comment: If I uninstall it, will it work the next time I visit stackoverflow?

Comment: No. Which is what you're asking for: Only click the button **once**.

Comment: I mean that the script should not keep clicking on the link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you "click that button", it causes a new page to load, which causes the userscript to run again, which clicks that button... And the cycle repeats continually.
(Note that due to the nature of `waitForKeyElements`, each script instance *does* only click once.  The script is just getting relaunched continually.)

So, obviously you do not really want to click that button every time.
The question is: "**How do you determine which page-loads to click the button on and which ones to leave alone?**"

Then you need to add persistent logic -- that survives page (re)loads -- to your script to make that distinction.

One crude way is to assume that if you have clicked within the last, say, 10 seconds, that you do not want to click again.
Here's what that logic looks like in a Greasemonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _ChromeC
// @match    *://stackoverflow.com/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_setValue
// @grant    GM_getValue
// ==/UserScript==

const delayBetweenClicks    = 10000;  //-- 10000 = 10 seconds
var   oldUnixTime           = parseInt (GM_getValue ("Last_redirect", "0"), 10);
console.log ("oldUnixTime: ", oldUnixTime);

waitForKeyElements ("#interestingTags a", clickOnlyOccassionally);

function clickOnlyOccassionally (jNode) {
    var currentTime = (new Date() ).getTime ();

    // Only click if we haven't done so in a while...
    if ( (currentTime - oldUnixTime) > delayBetweenClicks) {
        GM_setValue ("Last_redirect", `${currentTime}`);  //  Must store as string.

        var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
}
```